# Android Studio в буквальном смысле не работает визуальный редактор макетов

Tags: android, android-studio

Я нигде ничего не нашёл за полчаса поиска. Дело в том, что когда я добавляю новый элемент в макет, то редактор внезапно перестаёт показывать "экран" моего приложения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но так происходит не всегда. Например, обычная кнопка добавляется успешно, а когда я попытался добавитьTabLayout, то случилось это. В самом коде **ошибок нет**, и он без проблем работает на телефоне.

Помогите решить, если кто знает как!

P.S. Такая фигня на версиях Electric Eel и Flamingo RC